# Probability of next two draws one white ball is drawn

Tags: probability

A box contains 12 red and 6 white balls. Balls are drawn from the box one at a time without replacement. If in 6 draws there are at least 4 white balls, find the probability that exactly one white is drawn in the next two draws.

My method is this: first we choose 4W balls and 2 red balls and then arrange in themselves and that gives $\binom{12}{2}*\binom{6}{4}$ ways and then distributing it in $\frac{6!}{4!2!}$ ways. Similarly other two cases being 5W,1R and 6W, which gives total of $\binom{12}{1}\binom{6}{5}\frac{6!}{5!}$ and $\binom{12}{0}\binom{6}{6}\frac{6!}{6!}$.

And now multiplying with $\binom{10}{1}\binom{2}{1}*2!$ in first one, similarly $\binom{11}{1}*\binom{1}{1}*2!$ And last one "0" as there is no way we can draw a white ball as all are finished in first six draws.

This accounts for next two drawing in which one should comes a white ball. But this is not the given answer as the total favourable outcomes (that is intereection outcomes) what's wrong with this method ?

Comment: It is unclear what "outcomes" should be considered the "same" or "different" to others, and it is also unclear why we care about the count of these outcomes as they might not be equally likely to occur as one another depending on how we phrase things.  In order to help facilitate calculations it is often preferred to consider all balls here as being distinct even if to our eyes they might be indistinguishable.  Imagine each ball has a hidden label inside of the ball that we can't see unless we cut it open.  You did this for your $\binom{12}{2}\binom{6}{4}$ but ignored it for "distributing it"

Comment: Your calculation is incomplete and unclear, but it appears that you are not computing a conditional probability here.  Rather you appear to be computing the intersection...that is, the probability that at least $4W$ are chosen in the first $6$ draws AND at least $1W$ appears in the next $2$ draws.  Though, as I said, your calculation is unclear.

Comment: Actually i was interested mainly in the intersectiom outcomes because thats where i was making mistake

Comment: @JMoravitz yeah i choosed those but then it needs to be distributed too right ? I wasnt able to get that , i think thats where my mistake is also

Comment: Actually i think my whole problem is just that only when we consider arranging of the indistiguishable balls to be like my way and when not and the reason , that is all i need as the answer to this problem